# Doctrine 2 и Relations

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine2

Есть 2 таблицы.

```
<?php

namespace DCS\Entity;
/**
 * DCS\Entity\DcsSpectators
 *
 * @Table(name="dcs_spectators")
 * @Entity
 */
class DcsSpectators
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer $pilotId
     * @Column(name="pilot_id", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $pilotId;
```

В этой таблице хранятся ссылки(pilot_id) на другую таблицу (foreign key).

Вторая таблица-список пилотов.

```
<?php

namespace DCS\Entity;
/**
 *
 *
 * @Table(name="pilots")
 * @Entity
 *
 */
class Pilots
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $nickname
     *
     * @Column(name="nickname", type="string", length=128, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $nickname;
```

как правильно прописать в аннотациях связи между этими таблицами? 
Опробовал разные методы, ничто не работает.

Zend Framework 1.12.17.

```
 <?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        $this->doctrine = Zend_Registry::get('doctrine');
        $this->entityManager = $this->doctrine->getEntityManager();
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $pilots = new DCS\Entity\Pilots();
        $red = new DCS\Entity\DcsRedteam();
        $blue = new DCS\Entity\DcsBlueteam();
        $spectators = $this->entityManager->getRepository('DCS\Entity\DcsSpectators')->findAll();
        foreach($spectators as $spectator){
            echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($spectator);
        }
        $info = $pilots->getMainPageInfo($this->entityManager);
        $redteam = $red->getList($this->entityManager);
        $blueteam = $blue->getList($this->entityManager);

        $this->view->redteam = $redteam;
        $this->view->blueteam = $blueteam;
        $this->view->flight_players = $info;
    }

}
```

После выполнения данного кода, я получаю массив Спектаторов, но...данные с другой таблицы `Pilots` не присоединятся ни через Inner ни через Left join. 
Запрос через createQuery писать не хочу, через queryBuilder аналогично не хочу.

В результате я хочу получить все записи из таблицы DCS_Spectators и присоединенное поле Pilots.nickname со 2й таблицы.

Как правильно прописать в аннотациях классов связи между этими таблицами в Doctrine 2? Как можно выполнять дебаг для Entities? То есть, когда я через метод `getRepository('Entity')` - вызываю метод `findAll()` - хотелось бы отслеживать, какой генерируется запрос `SELECT`.
Спасибо.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы. Вопрос уже не актуален. Я уже разобрался хорошо в работе с Доктрином.

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score -1):

При связи с другой таблицей, необходимо указать поля через которые эти таблицы связаны и тип свзяи

[подробнее тут](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)

Если связь @OneToOne

```
 
/**
 * One Spec has One Pilot
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Pilot")
 * @JoinColumn(name="pilot_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $pilot
```

Comment: Старайтесь давать более развернутые ответы. Содержимое при переходе по ссылке может измениться, или просто стать недоступным.

Comment: Автор не указал тип связи между таблицами. Это OneToOne, OneToMany или ManyToOne.